# Initializing an array of relative coordinates of all adjacent 2D matrix cells

Tags: functional-programming, matrix, j

The program should output this:

```
_1 _1
_1  0
_1  1
 0 _1
 0  1
 1 _1
 1  0
 1  1
```

Currently I have this code:

```
(4 ~: i.9) # (3 # i:1) ,. 9 $ i:1
```

But I think it can be better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution relies excessively on magic numbers, such as 9 and 3.  It also obscures the Cartesian-product aspect of the problem.  Therefore, I think it could be better written as:

```
(< (< (< 4))) { ,/ > { ;~i:1
```

### Derivation

- `(i:1)` produces the list `_1 0 1`.
- `{ (i:1) ; (i:1)` produces the [Cartesian product](http://jsoftware.2058.n7.nabble.com/Cartesian-products-tp1234p1235.html):

  ```
  ┌─────┬────┬────┐
  │_1 _1│_1 0│_1 1│
  ├─────┼────┼────┤
  │0 _1 │0 0 │0 1 │
  ├─────┼────┼────┤
  │1 _1 │1 0 │1 1 │
  └─────┴────┴────┘
  ```

  @earl points out that this reflexive expression can be written more succinctly as `{;~i:1`.
- `>` unboxes it into a 3 × 3 × 2 matrix, and `,/` flattens it into a 9 × 2 matrix:

  ```
  _1 _1
  _1  0
  _1  1
   0 _1
   0  0
   0  1
   1 _1
   1  0
   1  1
  ```
- The only remaining task is to [exclude](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/learning/06.htm) the `0 0` row, which is element 4.  The `(< (< (<4))) {` selector seems to do this job.

Comment: Is there a difference between `,&<` and `;`?

Comment: `;` seems to work just as well as `,&<` so I have incorporated your suggestion into the answer.

Comment: Another minor improvement: the repetitive `(i:1);(i:1)` could also be written using the reflexive form: `;~i:1`.

Comment: isn't (<(<(<4))) the same as (<<<4)?

Comment: How about using the difference `-.` to remove `0 0`? As in, `0 0 -.~ ,/ > { ;~i:1`. I believe it's much more idiomatic compared to removing an item by an index that could change if you increase the distance from 1.